# Using common component for handling error in reactive form will affect performance in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-changedetection, angular2-docheck

In my project I'm having lots of forms each form contains 50 - 90 fields I'm using reactive form for each field there are set of validations. I have created a common component to display error to make the component readable as below.

```
        <div class="position-relative">
          <span class="input-icon material-icons-outlined">
            person_outline
          </span>
          <input
            type="text"
            formControlName="username"
            class="form-control"
            aria-label="User Name"
          />
          <app-form-error
            [controlerName]="formControls['username']"
            [errorMessages]="{ required: 'Please enter the user name' }"
          ></app-form-error>
        </div>
```

This is my form error component:

```
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  DoCheck,
  Input,
} from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-error',
  templateUrl: './form-error.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-error.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class FormErrorComponent implements DoCheck {
  @Input() controlerName: AbstractControl = new FormControl();
  @Input() errorMessages?: { [key: string]: string };

  errorMessage: string | null = null;

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.controlerName = new FormControl();
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    this.renderErrorMessage();
  }

  private renderErrorMessage() {
    this.errorMessage = null;
    if (this.controlerName && this.controlerName.touched) {
      for (const propertyName in this.controlerName.errors) {
        if (
          propertyName in this.controlerName.errors &&
          this.controlerName.touched &&
          this.errorMessages &&
          propertyName in this.errorMessages
        ) {
          this.errorMessage = this.errorMessages[propertyName];
          break;
        }
      }
      this.cd.markForCheck();
    }
  }
}
```

I have found one code and introduced Change detection but even though it is triggering multiple times. Consider the scenario im having two fields username and password if i touched both the field already if i start change something on the username both is getting triggered because they already touched. Will this cause performance issue for large form how to handle error message efficiently ?.